# Why is the Log Stream Empty for My Node App on Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure

My node app on azure does not log anything: The log stream is empty.

The app is shown as "running" in the overview panel.
Application Logging is set to "on" and "verbose".

[image]

myserver.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logstream:

[image]

Server Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');


// repeatedly log every 2 minutes a test message to console
setInterval(() => {
  console.log('test');
}, 120000);

const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));


// simple ping - pong
app.get('/api/ping', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'pong' });
});

app.listen(80, () => console.log('Server running on port 80'));`
```

Tried :
added a  IISNode.yml  file to my project, with the entry loggingEnabled: true

Comment: Adding the logs and log levels will trace the logs in the Log stream

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same code as yours, And received no logs

[image]

- Adding the logs and log levels will trace the logs in the Log stream.
- The below code is for an Express.js application in Node.js that includes logging using the Winston library.
- The below Express.js application with logging capabilities using Winston, handles requests on two routes and provides error handling for the server.

```js
// app.js


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Create a logger instance with different log levels
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: winston.format.combine(
    winston.format.colorize(),
    winston.format.timestamp(),
    winston.format.printf(({ timestamp, level, message }) => {
      return `${timestamp} [${level}] ${message}`;
    })
  ),
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'sam.log' }) // Logs to a file
  ]
});

// Middleware for logging requests
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  logger.info(`${req.method} ${req.url}`);
  next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, World!');
});

app.get('/api/ping', (req, res) => {
  logger.info('Received a ping request');
  res.json({ message: 'pong' });
});

// Error handling middleware
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  logger.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('Something went wrong!');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  logger.info(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

**Local:**

[image]

[image]

**Log stream:**

[image]